# Find week number of the month from today() date using formula field in salesforce

Tags: apex, community, salesforce1-app, formula

I want to Find week number of the month from today() date using formula field in salesforce.

On developer forum sites, I am getting the formula for week number of year but My requirement is to find week number of the month by using today's date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula

```
(6+DAY(Date_Field__c+1-WEEKDAY(Date_Field__c-1)))/7
```

Make sure you use formula type = Number with 0 decimal places

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620712/excel-formula-to-get-week-number-in-month-having-monday)